# Is it possible to find the url height and tab height in browser (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to find the maximum inner height of a browser no matter if it's in full screen or not. So I'm trying to subtract the height of URL and Tabs from windows.availHeight. Is this possible?

I would appreciate it if there is any better alternative solution.

Comment: Don't know how to measure but `window.innerHeight` should work ?

Comment: No, but Window.innerHeight value changes when browser resizes, so I can't use that

Comment: So you need inner height assuming browser is full screen( no matter whats the current size) ?

Comment: Try it with `screen.height`.

Comment: Priyesh Kumar - Yea thats right

Comment: If browser is in full screen, then it wont have any toolbar( except when you hover on top). so `screen.height` is perfect

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried document.documentElement.clientHeight, it changes when the browser enters fullscreen.

Comment: That's not what OP is looking for. It changes when browser is resized